# How can I review custom privileges?

Tags: permission, sharing, group, acl

The *Get Info* box for an external hard drive shows "Custom" under *Privileges* in section *Sharing & Permissions*. Interestingly this is for groups with these names

- com.apple.sharepoint.group.6
- com.apple.sharepoint.group.5

[image: Strange name and privileges]

I have no idea how they were created, let alone what they are. Are these groups created as a result of any known process and what are these "Custom" privileges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found out is that the "Custom" privilege means that permissions have been configured in a way that are more complex than is provided and can be shown in the basic user settings of the *Get Info* window (namely: Read, Write, No Access).

If I query the volume in Terminal with `ls -leda /Volumes/Some\ HD/` I get something like this.  Option `e` is to print the ACL associated with the file (or directory), if present, in long (`-l`) output.

```
drwx------+ 18 Alex  staff  680  1 Oct 18:19 /Volumes/Some\ HD/
 0: group:com.apple.sharepoint.group.6 allow search
 1: group:com.apple.sharepoint.group.5 allow search
 2: D93ABBA3-3566-4A08-878E-B2E7C575B4A6 allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity
```

I just still don't know where the com.apple.sharepoint.group users are coming from and `D93ABBA3-3566-4A08-878E-B2E7C575B4A6` looks a bit cryptic if that's me.